# Finding vertical projection of $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{b}$

Tags: vectors

I want to find the vertical or you could say perpendicular component of $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{b}$ 
Now I know that it can be found out using $\vec{a} - \left(\frac{a\cdot b}{|b|}\right)\vec{b}$

However I wanted to know why it cannot be found out using this method I tried. What is the flaw in it?
$\vec{a}\times\vec{b} = |a||b|\sin{\theta}\hat{n}$
Now $\hat{n}$ should be equal to $\frac{(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})}{|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|}$ 
Using this I can write the expression as $\vec{a}\times\vec{b} = |a||b|\sin{\theta}\times$$\frac{(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})}{|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|}$ which on simplifying gives me 
$\frac{|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|}{|b|} = |a|\sin{\theta}$ which I believe should be the perpendicular component

Now I'm probably doing something really stupid but I can't really understand where am I going wrong ? Please help me out with the same. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not a flaw but a conceptual remark: the first formula you gave works for vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ of any dimension. However, the cross product is only defined for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is more limiting.

Comment: I have added `\left` & `\right` to parentheses to make them bigger and replaced a period mark with `\cdot` for a scalar product.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the maginitude of the transverse component of $\vec{a}$ relative to the direction $\hat{b} = \vec{b}/|\vec{b}|$ is given by $|\vec{a} \times \hat{b}|$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$.  However, this does not tell you the direction of of the transverse component.

It's direction is not along $\hat{n}$, $\vec{a} \cdot \hat{n} =0$; it's direction is along $\hat{n} \times \hat{b}$.

Of course, all of this cross-product stuff only works in 3 dimensions.